# Create new array with key from an existing array - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have this hash:

```
my_hash = [
  {
    :name=> 'fiat 500',
    :things=> %w[gps bluetooth automatico],
    :year=> '2021'
  },
  {
    :name=> 'fusca',
    :things=> %w[som dvd automatico],
    :year=> '2022'
  }

]
```

I want to create a new array but only with the key :year, where would be like this:

```
 new_array = [
 {
    :year=> '2021'
  },
  {
    :year=> '2022'
  }
]
```

I'm a beginner in ruby ​​and I can't do it.

Comment: _"I have this hash: `my_hash = [...]`"_ – that's actually an array.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`slice`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Hash.html#method-i-slice) methods:

```
new_array = my_array.map { |item| item.slice(:year) }
```

Comment: just for note, between the 2 answers.  in the case that there is no "year" in a record of the array, this one returns an empty hash, and the other answer returns a hash with the `:year` set to `nil`

Comment: That's true. As it's not stated in the question I assume that the key is always present.

Comment: Instead of my_array, it should be my_hash - @Yakov

Comment: @BhushanKalode it's `my_hash` in the question, but actually, it's an array of hashes

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method map for that.

Ruby doc: https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map

```rb
new_array = my_hash.map { |h| { :year => h[:year] } }
```

Comment: sorry, I accidentally edited your answer instead of mine. I've reverted it back.